# Need to sum a column if 2 or 3 columns contain a specific text

Tags: excel, find, sumifs

I've the following data set and want to add the values that reflect "ABC" in any cell.

```
      Column1      Column 2      Column 3     Column 4   Column 5   
      ABC is good    CNN           $150         ABC       NBA
      Better life    N-H           $40          LIT       MNM
      Nice Job       ABC is good   $35          MN        ABC
      Poor           H-I           $200         ITL       ABC
      Best           TI            $120         SQL       ABC  
      Poor life      N-T           $40          LT        NM
      Great          BE            $800         ABC       BEF
```

The sum it should return is $150+$35+200+120+$400 = $905 because somewhere in the cells it has the text "ABC". I tried using sumif(find) formula but gives me value error. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean only Column 4 or Column 5? And why is the last number getting summed up $400? Shouldn't it be $800?

Comment: Yap, typo!!! It should be 150+35+200+120+800 = $1305. And not just column 4 or 5. Note, even Column 1 and 2 have "ABC" in their fields.

Comment: Would macro be fine?

Comment: I would prefer without macro if it works, if not vB it is.

Comment: @DK This can be done without VBA don't worry

Comment: Do those columns comprise a contiguous range, e.g. A1:E7?

Comment: @chancea I know I'm trying to get Index find or address in the formulae but aint getting it right. 
XorLX  -  It's a continuous range till 1500 rows!! I've more columns and rows  in my actual table.

Comment: I got a working formula.  Just typing out my explanation now

Comment: `SUMIFS` might be able to work.  But I don't believe so because `SUMIFS` "and's" the criteria together instead of "or's"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Answer

Use this array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"ABC",""))<LEN(A:A),1,0)+IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B:B,"ABC",""))<LEN(B:B),1,0)+IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D:D,"ABC",""))<LEN(D:D),1,0)+IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E:E,"ABC",""))<LEN(E:E),1,0)>0,1,0),C:C)
```

*Note: array formulas are entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>*

#### Explaination

To test whether or not a cell contains `ABC` we can use the `SUBSTITUTE` forumla combined with a `LEN` to test the difference between the string lengths:

`LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"ABC",""))<LEN(A:A)`

We can then wrap that in an `IF` statement to get a nice array of 1's and 0's

`IF(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"ABC",""))<LEN(A:A),1,0)`

If we mapped this out for your data it would look like this:

```
IF(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"ABC",""))<LEN(A:A),1,0) = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
IF(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B:B,"ABC",""))<LEN(B:B),1,0) = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}
IF(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D:D,"ABC",""))<LEN(D:D),1,0) = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
IF(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E:E,"ABC",""))<LEN(E:E),1,0) = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
                                                 += {0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1}
```

All we have to do then is check if the number in the array is `>0` and multiply it by column C using `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
      {0, 2,   0,  2,  1,   1,   0,  1  }
>0    {0, 1,   0,  1,  1,   1,   0,  1  }
*C:C  {0, 150, 40, 35, 200, 120, 40, 800}
=     {0, 150, 0,  35, 200, 120, 0,  800}
-----------------------------------------
SUM = 1305
```

Comment: @DK glad it works, sorry about all my silly typos.  They should all be fixed now

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Made my day. I'll look into adding on a criteria to this formula. Lets say if I've another column with year (2014,2015,2013 etc....) What if I want to see anything in 2014 or 2015..

Comment: Yeah you can add more columns.  It is going to get really expensive though since array formulas take a long time to calculate.  You can minimize this by just selecting the range that your data is at instead of the whole columns.  But if you have like column F as a year just add another `+IF(F:F=2014,1,0)+IF(F:F=2015,1,0)`.  or if the cell is a full date you can use `+IF(YEAR(F:F)=2014,1,0)+IF(YEAR(F:F)=2015,1,0)` or if the column is just text like before with ABC you can use the `SUBSTITUTE` + `LEN` method

Comment: Right. I didn't do entire column, I selected the range for the data which kills my wait time to half.

Comment: That's a beautiful explanation and an interesting use of `SUBSTITUTE` and `LEN`.  This might be the long way to the answer though. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since we are looking for `ABC` in any of the cells, we can use `CONCATENATE-FIND` to join all the cells together and then find `ABC` in the new string.  This saves a ton of code and simplifies the logic.  It always makes it easier to expand to more cells.

**Ranges for reference**

[image: ranges]

**Formula** in `G1`.  This is an array formula (enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).

```
=SUM(IF(ISERR(FIND("ABC",CONCATENATE(A1:A7,B1:B7,D1:D7,E1:E7))), 0, C1:C7))
```

**How it works**

- `CONCATENATE` forms a single large string with all the columns combined
- `FIND` looks for `ABC` in that single string.  It will return a number if found and an error (`#VALUE`) otherwise.
- `ISERR` checks if the error was returned
- `IF` decides if the value in column `C` should be returned or a `0` based on that error
- `SUM` takes all of those numbers and adds them

Comment: :O I didn't think concatenate could take arrays

Comment: @chancea, It can't take them... but it can go row-by-row in an array formula!

Comment: Now I feel like I over complicated things :D this is much simpler

Comment: That gives the same result!! didn't know concatenate would take arrays but thanks for the solution!!

Comment: @DK, pretty much everything will take an array inside an array formula. It just goes row-by-row.

Comment: How about I add more criteria? Basically how many "ABCs" in the CNN, How many "ABCs" in NiceJob.?